# Expected numbers of turns to generate k distinct elements

Tags: probability, expected-value, coupon-collector

There is a random number generator. It generates numbers between $1$ and $n$ with equal probability. What is the expected number of turns for it to generate k distinct numbers?

EDIT: My approach is to generate random numbers until I get $k$ distinct elements. Then, the answer will be the number of tries it has taken. I am not sure whether this is correct or not.

How to approach these types of questions? I need an algorithm for this.

Comment: Your approach is not correct. You may obtain $k$ distinct numbers in $k$ tries, while your peer may obtain $k$ distinct numbers in $k+1$ tries. So what is the answer, $k$ or $k+1$?

Comment: thanks. got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a truncated coupon collector's problem. The expected number of tries to get the first distinct coupon is $\frac nn$, the second distinct coupon $\frac n{n-1}$ more and so on until the $k$th distinct coupon takes $\frac n{n-k+1}$ tries on average. Thus the expected number of tries to get $k$ distinct coupons is
$$n\sum_{m=n-k+1}^n\frac1m$$

Comment: In the explanation above shouldn't it be `(n-1)/n`, `(n-k+1)/n` ?

Comment: @utkarshg I said expected number of tries. The number of tries to pull out the $k$th distinct coupon _after_ having pulled out $k-1$ distinct ones before that is a geometric random variable with probability of success $\frac{n-k+1}n$, hence the expected number of tries is its reciprocal.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks